# (jagged array) Array of an Array: automatically create in while loop, how to initialize?

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to create an array of an array from a text file...

There are 20000 line with 21 strings in each line separated by ',' .

I would like to read each line and make it into an array , each line being a new array within.

So I wanted to create the jagged array by starting it like this:

string[][] SqlArray = new string[200000][21];

But it gives: *ERROR MESSAGE : Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ]*

How would I create this array or initialize it?

I will be populating the data in the array like this:

while (true)
            {

```
            string theline = readIn.ReadLine();
            if (theline == null) break;

            string[] workingArray = theline.Split(',');

            for (int i = 0; i < workingArray.Length; i++)
            {

                for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
            {
               SqlArray[i][k] = workingArray[k];

             }


            }
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That type of initialization only works in Java. You must declare an array of arrays then initialize each in a loop.

```
string[][] SqlArray = new string[21][];
for(int index = 0; index < SqlArray.Length; index++)
{
    SqlArray[index] = new string[2000000];
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a non-jagged array. It will probably work for what you need.

```
string[,] SqlArray = new string[21 , 2000000];
```

It can be accessed like so:

```
SqlArray[2,6264] = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is interested this is how I ended up implementing it:

```
   TextReader readIn = File.OpenText("..\\..\\datafile.txt");
```

string[][] SqlArray = new string[rowNumCreate][];

```
        int e = 0;

        while (true)
        {

            string theline = readIn.ReadLine();
            if (theline == null) break;

            string[] workingArray = theline.Split(',');

            SqlArray[e] = new string[valuesInRow +1];

            for (int k = 0; k < workingArray.Length; k++)
            {

                SqlArray[e][k] = workingArray[k];

            }

            e++;

        }
```

The file being read is a simple mock database set as a flat file that was auto-generated to test an algorithm that I am implementing, which works with jagged arrays; hence instead of working with a data base I just created this for ease of use and to increase and decrease size at will.

Here is the code to build the text file:

Random skill_id;

skill_id = new Random();
            // int counter =0;

```
        string seedvalue = TicksToString();
        int rowNumCreate = 200000;
        int valuesInRow = 20;


        string lineInFile = seedvalue;
        string delimiter = ",";


        for (int i = 0; i < rowNumCreate; i++)
        {

            for (int t = 0; t < valuesInRow; t++)
            {

                int skill = skill_id.Next(40);

                string SCon = Convert.ToString(skill);

                lineInFile += delimiter + SCon;

            }

            if (rowNumCreate >= i + 1)
            {
                dataFile.WriteLine(lineInFile);
                lineInFile = "";


                string userPK = TicksToString();
                lineInFile += userPK;

            }

        }

        dataFile.Close();



    public static string TicksToString()
    {
        long ms = DateTime.Now.Second;
        long ms2 = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        Random seeds;
        seeds = new Random();
        int ran = seeds.GetHashCode();

        return string.Format("{0:X}{1:X}{2:X}", ms, ms2, ran).ToLower();
    }
```

I am still a student so not sure if the code is A-grade but it works :)